# Rqc file format not detected or supported r shiny

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny, fastq

I want to upload a fastq file and render some plots using Rqc Package especially the rqcQA function.

This is the code :

```
library(shiny)
library(Rqc)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                  accept = c('.fastq')
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot1")
      )
    ))

  server <- function(input, output) {
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        # folder <- "D:/sample.fastq"
      rqcResultSet <- rqcQA(inFile$datapath, workers=1)
        rqcReadQualityBoxPlot(rqcResultSet)
      })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I got an error while reading the input :

> 'rqcQA' : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : File format not detected or supported: 0

When i replace `inFile$datapath` by `folder` variable, i don't get any errors:

```
folder <- "D:/sample.fastq"
rqcResultSet <- rqcQA(folder, workers=1)
```

I did some research and i found the source code in Github, [detectFileFormat.R](https://github.com/Bioconductor-mirror/Rqc/blob/master/R/detectFileFormat.R) is the file containing the function which specify the type format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @NicE, the problem here is `rqcQA()` accept only FASTQ format, i posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321677/specify-file-format-output-fileinput-in-r-shiny) trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file is renamed to `0` when you upload it to shiny and doesn't pass the `rqcQA` file tests. Try running:

```
file.rename(inFile$datapath,inFile$name)
rqcResultSet <- rqcQA(inFile$name,workers=1)
```

This just renames the file to the original name in the current wd.

You can alternatively do

```
rqcResultSet <- rqcQA(FastqFile(inFile$datapath))
```

to skip the file check.